# XPath do not select nested matches

Tags: html, xml, xpath

Suppose I have this:

```html
<el class="classname">
  ...
  <el class="classname">
  </el>
  ...
</el>
<el class="classname">
 ...
  <el class="classname">
    ...
    <el class="classname">
    </el>
    ...
  </el>
 ...
</el>
```

Can I get only the two top-level  (without the nested ones), provided this XPath should be relative (i.e. if I matched one of these  beforehand I can add the same XPath and it will still work

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to do. XPath selects nodes. A node includes everything within. You can construct the expression to select the top-level nodes but you cannot “remove” content from those selected nodes.

Comment: The moment you select the parents, they include child nodes. For removing nodes, you can use javascript or another programming language.

Comment: Perhaps I did not quite accurately describe the question. I need to MATCH only top <el> and not match any <el> inside.

Answer (score 4):

Lets say your xml looks like this:

```
<root>
  <div>
    <div>
      <el class="classname" id="a1">
        <div>
          <el class="classname" id="a2">
            <div>
              <el class="classname" id="a3">
                <div>
                  <el class="classname" id="a4"/>
                </div>
              </el>
            </div>
          </el>
          <el class="classname" id="a5">
            <div>
              <el class="classname" id="a6">
                <div>
                  <el class="classname" id="a7"/>
                </div>
              </el>
            </div>
          </el>
        </div>
      </el>
    </div>
  </div>
  <el class="classname" id="a8">
    <div>
      <el class="classname" id="a9">
        <div>
          <el class="classname" id="a10">
            <div>
              <el class="classname" id="a11"/>
            </div>
          </el>
        </div>
      </el>
    </div>
  </el>
</root>
```

you can use the count on ancestor's to get the correct level. For the first level use XPath:

```
//el[@class='classname'][count(ancestor::el[@class='classname'])=0]
```

will only select el-elements with `@id="a1"` and `@id="a8"`

For the second level use this XPath:

```
//el[@class='classname'][count(ancestor::el[@class='classname'])=1]
```

This will select the `@id="a2"`, `@id="a5"` and `@id="a9"`

For the third level use :

```
//el[@class='classname'][count(ancestor::el[@class='classname'])=2]
```

This will select the `@id="a3"`, `@id="a6"` and `@id="a10"`

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this to go one level deeper: //el[@class="classname"][not(ancestor::el[@class="classname"])]//el[@class="classname"][not(ancestor::el[@class="classname"])]

Comment: Instead of counting ancestors, for the first level you could just do `/root/el`.

Comment: @derloopkat: correct, but  the OP question suggested that these elements could be anywhere. I wil adjust the example.